# MATLAB Storing a value which is updated continously

Tags: string, matlab, user-interface, store, updating

I have a MATLAB GUI (by GUIDE) which helps me to do some calculations..

I have a 'calculate' push button which calculates a new weight and x value every time that I click to  it (and manipulate inputs)

I need to store that 2 value in a matrix form but I dont know how to it. So it needs to create a matrix which is equal to the length of calculate values and store them..

A loop which counts number of clicks to 'calculate' can help but I am not sure.

Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: Is your gui created with guide?

Comment: Yes, it is created with a guide

Comment: Ok, I see, what I mean is if it was created with GUIDE, but I guess you understood. Anyway, what you need to do is to write what you want to do inside the callback function that is created along with the button. The data can be passed along to and from the function using the (I think) 3rd argument handles [link to documentation](http://se.mathworks.com/help/matlab/creating_guis/write-callbacks-using-the-guide-workflow.html)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is some simple code which I think does what you want. I created a 'programmatic' GUI for the purpose of demonstration, but it's easy to implement in your GUIDE code. Specifically, look at the `CalculateCallback`, which is the callback executed when the user presses the pushbutton used to 'calculate'. Here there is no calculation/data manipulation per se, the code only takes the user inputs from the text boxes and updates a matrix with the values. There is also a counter to keep track of the number of calculation.

The code is commented si it should be easy to follow. If not please ask for clarifications!

```
function CalculateGUI

clear
clc
close all

%// Create figure and uielements
handles.fig = figure('Position',[440 500 500 150]);

handles.CalcButton = uicontrol('Style','Pushbutton','Position',[60 70 80 40],'String','Calculate','Callback',@CalculateCallback);

handles.Val1Text = uicontrol('Style','Text','Position',[150 100 60 20],'String','Value 1');
handles.Val1Edit = uicontrol('Style','Edit','Position',[150 70 60 20],'String','');

handles.Val2Text = uicontrol('Style','Text','Position',[220 100 60 20],'String','Value 2');
handles.Val2Edit = uicontrol('Style','Edit','Position',[220 70 60 20],'String','');

handles.MatrixText = uicontrol('Style','Text','Position',[290 125 100 20],'String','Value 1 Value 2');
handles.MatrixEdit = uicontrol('Style','Text','Position',[300 25 80 100]);

handles.CounterText1 = uicontrol('Style','Text','Position',[40 20 80 20],'String','Loop counter');
handles.CounterText2 = uicontrol('Style','Text','Position',[130 20 80 20],'String','');

%// Initialize counter to get # of values calculated
handles.CalculateCounter = 0;
handles.MatrixValues = zeros(1,2);

guidata(handles.fig,handles); %// Save handles structure of GUI. IMPORTANT

    function CalculateCallback(~,~)
        
        %// Retrieve elements from handles structure.
        handles = guidata(handles.fig);
        
        %// Get entries in text boxes. Assumes inputs are numbers.
        Val1 = str2double(get(handles.Val1Edit,'String'));
        Val2 = str2double(get(handles.Val2Edit,'String'));

        %// If 1st calculation, initialize the matrix containing the
        %// values. Otherwise, concatenate current values with existing matrix.
        if handles.CalculateCounter == 0
            handles.MatrixValues = [Val1,Val2];
        else
            handles.MatrixValues = [handles.MatrixValues; Val1,Val2];
        end
        
       %// Print matrix values in text box. 
       set(handles.MatrixEdit,'String',num2str(handles.MatrixValues));
       
       %// Update counter and display current value in GUI.
       handles.CalculateCounter = handles.CalculateCounter + 1;
       set(handles.CounterText2,'String',num2str(handles.CalculateCounter))
       guidata(handles.fig,handles); %// Save handles structure of GUI.
    end
end
```

Here is a screenshot of the GUI after some calculations:

[image]

Once you're done you can fetch the data from `handles.MatrixValues` and do whatever you want with them.
Hope that helps you get started!